# Fundamental issue in Inequality with absolute value function on one side but variables on both sides

Tags: functions, inequality, absolute-value

I have been taught that if $|f(x)| < a$, where $a$ is positive, then simply
$-a< f(x) <a,$ and this makes much sense to me.
My query is what if I have something like
$$|f(x)| < g(x)$$
Do I need to check when is $g(x)<0$ and exclude all those solutions?
Or can I ignore checking it and simply go for $-g(x)< f(x) < g(x)$
Here I am taking $g(x)$ a non constant function whose range includes both negative and positive values.
I tried to find examples by making my own questions where if I don't check for $g(x)<0,$ I get the wrong answer, but I couldn't frame any.

I'll give an example

Suppose |x²-3x+2| < x+1
Why don't I need to check x+1<0 and remove those solns from my answer?
I can directly go
-x-1 < x²-3x+2 < x+1 without caring for x+1.

Edit: I wasn't able to explain my query well. Kindly refer to [Inequality query related to absolute value function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672446/inequality-query-related-to-absolute-value-function/4672452#4672452) I have reframed my question.

Comment: There are no solutions if $|f(x)| < g(x) < 0$.

Comment: $|f(x)|<g(x)$ can never hold of $g(x) \leq 0$.

Comment: So do I need to check when is g(x)<0 or can I skip checking it?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to check when is $g(x)<0$ and exclude all those solutions?
> Or can I ignore checking it and simply go for $-g(x)< f(x) < g(x)$

You can ignore it and simply go for $-g(x)< f(x) < g(x)$. Because if $g(x)<0$ then in $-g(x)< f(x) < g(x)$ you have a positive number on the left and negative on the right. And so it cannot have a solution anyway. This is even true if $g(x)\leq 0$. Or equivalently: if $-g(x)< f(x) < g(x)$ has a solution that $g(x)>0$ has to hold.

Comment: Sir I wasn't able to explain my query well. I have framed a new question (I am new to the site) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672446/inequality-query-related-to-absolute-value-function/4672452#4672452 , please see this

Comment: @Ashubh I'm not sure I follow. The other question is about $|f(x)|>g(x)$ inequality, which is different from $|f(x)|<g(x)$ and is governed by different rules.

Comment: With |f(x)| < g(x) I have a better understanding after your answer.

Comment: Speculating more about |f(x)| > g(x)